# Has "as" been deleted before "a prisoner" in this text?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

> A certain Meroujan, an Armenian, noble, jealous of the power and prosperity of Manuel, persuaded him that the Persian commandant in Armenia was about to seize his person, and either to send him a prisoner to Artaxerxes, or else to put him to death.

[[Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/16167/16167-h/16167-h.htm)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This is rather poetic writing, and the "as" in "as a prisoner" is implied. To make this more clear, the author could have written "to send him, a prisoner, to Artaxerxes," which would highlight that he would be a prisoner. He cannot be receiving a prisoner, as "to Artaxerxes" follows "send him a prisoner".

As you suggested the author also could have included "as a prisoner" (both with or without the comma).